# Android Mocking (@InjecktMock )

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

when I write this annotation

```
@InjectMock
ServerService service;
```

usually it will invoke the constructor of ServerService class, if there is empty constructor it works fine but if in that constructor there is some other field and other initialzation then it will through NullPointerException how to mock those objects that are with in constructor

Thanks :) help will be appriciated